# Using multiple UIWindow to avoid coupling

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm trying to implement a loading view which will globally represent the loading state of a screen. This view will be centred on the screen bounds rect.

This implementation will be independent from any ViewController, so my first guess would be to go for a method in the application delegate (let's name it : -(void)showLoaderView).

Is it a good option to make an other UIWindow which will contain the loading view. Once the app delegate method "showLoaderView" is called this window will be easily displayed on top of the other window.

The problem if I'm using regular views and addSubview method is that this create bad coupling as the position of the loader view will depend on the moment where -(void)showLoaderView will be called.

If you have any other suggestion regarding this problem please I'd enjoy reading them.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If your app is in a state where it will go directly to the view it was in before it went inactive then it won't need the loading screen as the resources will still be available.

You should only really see the loading screen if the app has been terminated completely and from that point you won't have a view to go back to other than the standard first view.

Because of this I'd just make a UIViewController that shows the loading view and then pushes to the main view.

**EDITING ANSWER FROM COMMENTS**

Make a separate xib for it

You could even make it a singleton with it's own method that grabs the UINavigationViewController from the appDelegate and then modally presents itself from the topViewController in the stack and then dismisses itself

Then anywhere in the app you can do `[[MyLoadingView sharedInstance] show];` or something and you get the modal view and when it finishes loading it will dismiss itself too.

**EDIT 2**

You can still push actions off to a BG thread.

Just use a NSOperationQueue.

Maybe you need a loading view for display purposes and a loading singleton class that actually does the work. That way the loading view can be dismissed and the loading class can still do the work in the background.

Comment: I want to make something really reusable without coupling. Anywhere in the code when I call showLoaderView, it should popup the loading view above all view in main UIWindow and that's it.

Comment: Good idea but then I will loose the hability to do action on the background view as the loading view will be modally presented.

Comment: Editied my answer to incorporate the comments.